# Linux server, upload a file to windows client (Socket)

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

**When i send the file to the client it gets corrupted, and with a size in bytes higher.**

I have a version of this server running on Windows and works perfectly,but I'm not having the same result on Linux.

The file size on disk may be the error in time to send the size in bytes to the client that runs on another platform?

**fread function is being used correctly?**

an **expert** can analyze and help find the error?

**LINUX SERVER SIDE**

```
// FUNCTION TO UPLOAD A FILE TO CLIENT WINDOWS
int Socket_Setup::FILE_UPLOAD(int iD, std::string DIR_UPLOAD)
{   
    char Block[1024]; 
    long FileSize;
    int BytesRead;  

    fp = fopen(DIR_UPLOAD.c_str(), "rb");
    if (!fp)
    {
          errno_message.append((char*)strerror(errno));
          FUNCTION_LOG(errno_message);
          return 1;
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    FileSize = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);

    long Size_Send = htonl(FileSize);
    Total = FileSize;

    // Sending the file size to the Windows Client  
    iResult = send(client[iD].socket, (const char*)&Size_Send, sizeof(long), 0);        
    if (iResult <= 0)
    {
          errno_message.append((char*)strerror(errno));
          FUNCTION_LOG(errno_message);
          return 1;
    }   

     // LOOP TO SEND FILE 
     while (FileSize > 0)
    {
        BytesRead = fread(Block, 1, sizeof(Block), fp);
        if (BytesRead <= 0)
        {
            errno_message.append((char*)strerror(errno));
            FUNCTION_LOG(errno_message);
            fclose(fp);
            return 1;
        }
        if (send(client[iD].socket, Block, BytesRead, 0) != BytesRead)
        {
            errno_message.append((char*)strerror(errno));
            FUNCTION_LOG(errno_message);
            fclose(fp);
            return 1;
        }
        FileSize -= BytesRead;      
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

**WINDOWS CLIENT SIDE:**

```
int readBytes(SOCKET s, void *buffer, int buflen)
    {
        int total = 0;
        char *pbuf = (char*)buffer;
        while (buflen > 0)
        {
            int iResult = recv(s, pbuf, buflen, 0);
            if (iResult < 0)
            {
                if (WSAGetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
                   continue;
                return SOCKET_ERROR;
            }
            else if (iResult == 0)
                return 0;
            else
            {
                pbuf += iResult;
                buflen -= iResult;
                total += iResult;
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
        // FUNCTION TO DOWNLOAD FILE FROM SERVER
        int Remote_Manip::FILE_DOWNLOAD(std::string directory, Socket_Setup &socket_setup)
        {   
            unsigned long FileSize;
            char mfcc[65535];

            File = fopen(directory.c_str(), "wb");
            if (File == NULL)
            {
                closesocket(socket_setup.ConnectSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }

            // Receiving file size from server
            int iResult = readBytes(socket_setup.ConnectSocket, &FileSize, sizeof(FileSize));
            if (iResult <= 0)
            {
                fclose(File);
                closesocket(socket_setup.ConnectSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }
            FileSize = ntohl(FileSize);

            // LOOP TO RECEIVING FILE
            while (FileSize > 0)
            {
                int Received = recv(socket_setup.ConnectSocket, mfcc, sizeof(mfcc),0);
                if (Received <= 0)
                {
                    fclose(File);
                    closesocket(socket_setup.ConnectSocket);
                    WSACleanup();
                    return 1;
                }

                if (fwrite(mfcc, 1, Received, File) != Received)
                {
                    fclose(File);
                    closesocket(socket_setup.ConnectSocket);
                    WSACleanup();
                    return 1;
                }
                    FileSize -= Received;
            }   
            fflush(File);
            fclose(File);
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: C++ is not C.  Tags edited.

Comment: Should we read anything into the parameter name `DIR_UPLOAD`?  You treat it as if it is the name of a regular file, but if so, that's a strange name for it.

Comment: DIR_UPLOAD It is entered by the User

Comment: You do not verify that all bytes of the file size are successfully sent.  That's *probably* not causing the issue, but `send()` and `write()` are not guaranteed to send the full contents of the specified buffer.  The return value tells you how many actually were sent.

Comment: You also do not verify that all bytes of each block of the file content are successfully sent.  This very likely *is* your problem.  Generally speaking, to send one buffer-full of data you must loop, each time `write()`ing or `send()`ing the unwritten tail of the buffer until you've sent all the bytes.

Comment: The server runs on Windows but not on Linux

Comment: You have to do the analogous thing on the receiving side, but you already do, albeit not quite the same way.  You do pay attention to how many bytes are received by each `recv()`, and you don't need to ensure you fill the buffer before writing it to a file because you instead track how many bytes of the overall file you have so far received.

Comment: Have you considered calling [sendfile](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile)? It seems like it would make things easier for you.

Comment: the server run on linux

Comment: What is the word length on both systems? Win64 is `LLLP64` ,i.e. `sizeof long == 4`, i.e. `long` is "only" 32bit. On the other hand, 64bit Linux  is LP64, meaning `sizeof long == 8` which makes quite a lot of difference for your code, because when receiving the file size, you read too much or too little. It doesn't matter for 32bit, but it matters for pure 64bit and 32/64bit mixes

Comment: How many bytes is the file size supposed to be in the protocol? And with what endianness is it supposed to be communicated?

Comment: I have a version of this server running on windows perfectly, I am trying to rewrite it in linux, but I'm having these problems at the time of upload, the file arrives with a different size in Windows client and corrupted!
what should I do ?

Comment: I think the problem is in time to send the file size, does anyone know a better way to  do this?

Comment: You might try sending the file size as `int64_t` or `int32_t` if there’s a size mismatch.

Comment: I solved my problem, thank you all !
I'm sending the file size with int64_t

Comment: You want to clean up the messy mixture of different integer types in use. Stick to `size_t` and `ssize_t` at least on the Linux side.

Comment: Also to not stumble over unexpected differences in how sender and receiver implement integers transfer the file's size as plain text.